# I am trying to find the factors of factorial of a number

Tags: c++, primes, factorial, prime-factoring

I am trying to solve the SPOJ problem DIVFACT where we need to find the factorial of a number. Though I used the correct formulae and at the same time I also checked the special case of 0 and 1,still I am getting wrong answer and it's really difficult for me to figure out what's wrong with my code. Can someone please help me figure out the problem? For reference I am providing the link to the problem:- [Link of the problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVFACT/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#define MOD 100000007
#define MAX 50001
#define pb push_back
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

ll no_of_factors(int num,vector<int> primes)
{
    ll result=1;
    for(int i=0;i<primes.size();i++)
    {
        if(primes[i]>num)
            break;
        ll k=primes[i];
        ll count=0;
        while(num/k!=0){
            count=(count+(num/k))%MOD;
            k=k*primes[i];
        }
        result=(result*((count+1)%MOD))%MOD;
    }
    return result;
}

vector<int> seive(){
    bool isPrime[MAX];
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=2;i<MAX;i++)
        isPrime[i]=true;
    
    for(int i=2;i*i<MAX;i++)
    {
        if(isPrime[i])
        {
            for(int j=i*i;j< MAX;j+=i)
                isPrime[j]=false;
        }
        
    }
    
    for(int i=2;i<MAX;i++)
    {
        if(isPrime[i])
            v.pb(i);
    }

    return v;
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int num;
        ll divisors;
        cin>>num;
        vector<int> v1;
        v1=seive();
        
        divisors=no_of_factors(num,v1);
        cout<<divisors<<endl;
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What answer are you getting? What answer do you expect? What is your input? What debugger do you have access to?

Comment: See also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `typedef long long ll;` why? `#define pb push_back` double why??

Comment: please explain within the question what the code is supposed to do, the input, the expected output and the actual output (a [mre])

Comment: btw once you made it produce correct results I would expect you hit the time limit. You are making unecessary copies of the vectors, and, more importantly, you are sieving the same numbers for each single test case

Comment: OT:  If you need to use macros or typedefs for abbreviations, consider taking a keyboarding class.  In there world of programming, there is a lot of typing, so acclimate.

Comment: Your prime number check should start at 3 and increment by 2.  You'll save half of your existing execution time.  The first prime is 2, all remaining primes are odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem states that the answer should be in `MOD 10^9+7` but you have mistakenly defined `MOD` as `10^8+7`.

Comment: Reminder, in C++ the symbol `^` is Exclusive OR.  The expression `10^9` is the same as `(10 Exclusive-Or 9)`.